# Solving a straightforward linear ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve this linear ODE, but I seem to get it wrong for some reason. 
$$\dfrac{dy}{dt}-\dfrac{1}{2}y(t)=2\cos t.$$

I get
$$y(t)=e^{t/2}(c+2 \sin t).$$

How can this be wrong? And yet it seems to be.

Comment: To answer your question, we should know how did your get your result. Namely, how have you found a particular solution of the non-homogeneous equation/in which form you were looking for it. I mean, given the right side, I would look for a particular solution in the form $A\cos t+B\sin t$. But what did you do? Variation of integration constant?

Comment: Got it. Sorry, I'm really tired.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hints:

- Solve for the homogenous, $y_h = c_1e^{t/2}$ (you got that right)
- Choose $y_p = a \cos t + b \sin t$, substitute back into ODE and solve for $a$ and $b$. What do you get? You should get $(a = -4/5 ~~\text{and}~~ b = 8/5)$
- $y = y_h + y_p$

Comment: @BabakS.: TU to yours too! :-) Hello my friend, hope all is well!

Comment: The hints did the job! ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Also, you can make the ODE exact by multiplying an appropriate function called *Integrating factor*. According to the general theory the if we have an standard form ODE like: $$y'+P(x)y=Q(x)$$ then $$\mu(x)=e^{\int P(x)dx}$$ is our wanted integrating factor. And after multiplying it to the original ODE we are led to have $$\frac{d}{dx}[\mu(x)y]=\mu(x)Q(x)\longrightarrow y(x)=\frac{1}{\mu(x)}\int\mu(x)Q(x)dx$$

Here, we have: $$\mu(x)=e^{\int\frac{-1}2dx}=e^{\frac{-1}2x}$$ and $$y(x)=e^{\frac{x}2}\int e^{\frac{-x}2}\times 2\cos(x)dx$$

Comment: Nice work, Babak! tu +